# Как использовать aliases с typescript + webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Получаю ошибку: Cannot find module '@components/test' or its corresponding type declarations.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */                     /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */              /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */           /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
alias: {
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components'),
            '@containers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'containers'),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это связано с тем, что .ts файлв не знают, к какому tsconfig.json они относятся.

В tsconfig.json нужно указать files и include, чтобы этот tsconfig использовался для работы с ts файлами.